# Postgres, update statement from jsonb array with sorting

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in my table - it contains array of json objects
one of fields in these objects is a date.
Now i added new column in my table of type timestamp.
And now i need statement which hepls me to update new column with most recent date value from jsonb array column af a same record.

Following statement works great on selecting most recent date from jsonb array column of certain record:

```
select history.date 
from document, 
     jsonb_to_recordset(document.history) as history(date date)  
where document.id = 'd093d6b0-702f-11eb-9439-0242ac130002'
order by history.date desc 
limit 1;
```

On update i have tried following:

```
update document 
  set status_recent_change_date = subquery.history.date
from (
   select id, history.date 
   from document, 
        jsonb_to_recordset(document.history) as history(date date)
) as subquery 
where document.id = subquery.id 
order by history.date desc 
limit 1;
```

Last statement does not working.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) UPDATE does neither support `order by` nor `limit` - if you really want to limit that to one row, you need to move that into the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e716f810da1e96107980b7db8e9ea3aa)

```
UPDATE document d
SET status_recent_change_date = s.date
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)                       
        *
    FROM document,
        jsonb_to_recordset(document.history) AS history(date date) 
    ORDER BY id, history.date DESC
) s 
WHERE d.id = s.id;
```

Using `LIMIT` would not work because you limit the entire output of your `SELECT` statement. But you want to limit the output of each document.id. This can be done using `DISTINCT ON (id)`.

This result can be used to update each record using their `id` values.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't need to use `LIMIT` command.

It is enough to do the sorting inside `SUBQUERY`:

```
UPDATE document SET status_recent_change_date = subquery.hdate
FROM (
  SELECT id, history.date AS hdate
  FROM document, jsonb_to_recordset(document.history) AS history(date date) 
  ORDER BY history.date DESC
) AS subquery 
WHERE document.id = subquery.id
```

Comment: error: "status_history" table absent in FROM statement

Comment: ERROR: ОШИБКА:  таблица "history" отсутствует в предложении FROM

Comment: Try to add alias for history.date. I've edit query

Comment: Yes, it should work? but i have used @S-Man example. Many thanks anyway)